# How to uninstall the redis installed from source in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, redis

I'd installed the redis-server on Ubuntu 12.04 from source.
But at somepoint it couldn't get installed fully, failed on last `make install` cmd.

Then I just installed via apt package.

Now I'm confused which installation is being run with which conf file?

Actually I'd like to uninstall/delete everything that installation via source did and simply want to go with the package installed one.

Comment: Take a look at this awesome blog post:
http://grainier.net/how-to-uninstall-redis-server-from-ubuntu/

Answer (score 7):

Go to source tree and try this command:

```
make uninstall
```

If that doesn't work you can list the steps that the software would take to install itself (without actually installing anything):

```
make -n install
```

Answer (score 5):

Following the 'make -n install' I was able to deduce that this should do the trick:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/redis-*
```

Answer (score 1):

I could successfully remove it by using following command on Ubuntu from terminal:

```
 $ sudo apt-get remove redis-server
```

Comment: How will that remove the one installed from source?  Surely, if anything, that will uninstall precisely the wrong one?